# PHP class implementing Serializable doesn't serialize

Tags: php, serialization, interface, serializable, php-5.4

What I was really looking for was a magic method `__toArray` for my class, but I guess such a thing doesn't exist, and the `ArrayAccess` interface doesn't match what I'm looking for.

I would like to be able to return a `json_encode`d representation of my object when `serialize` is called on it, instead of the traditional PHP string representation.

Here is an example of my code, which I can't get to work.

```
<pre>
<?php
class A implements Serializable {
    private $a,
        $b,
        $c;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->a = 1;
        $this->b = 2;
        $this->c = 3;
    }

    public function serialize () {
        return json_encode(array (
            'a' => $this->a,
            'b' => $this->b
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize ($serialized) {
    }
}

echo '<b>PHP version:</b> ',
    phpversion(),
    PHP_EOL,
    '<b>Serialized:</b> ',
    serialize(new A());
?>
</pre>
```

I know I'm implementing the interface correctly, because if I omit one of the methods, it displays an error. However, this is what my script returns:

> **PHP version:** 5.4.14
>
> **Serialized:** C:1:"A":13:{{"a":1,"b":2}}

If I instantiate an instance of `A` and call it like any old method, like so:

```
$a = new A();
$a->serialize();
```

It works as expected:

> **PHP version:** 5.4.14
>
> **Serialized:** {"a":1,"b":2}

Although this kind of defeats the purpose of using the `Serializable` interface.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about http://php.net/manual/fr/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php?

Like this :

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
class A implements JsonSerializable {
    private $a,
        $b,
        $c;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->a = 1;
        $this->b = 2;
        $this->c = 3;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'a' => $this->a,
            'b' => $this->b
        ];
    }

}
echo json_encode(new A(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$ php test.php 
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
}
```

But there is no `unserialize` function.

Do you really need to call serialize on it?

Comment: I didn't even know such an interface existed, but this is exactly what I needed! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how the `Serializable` interface works.

The output in your second example doesn't have any information about the class. `serialize()` should return only the string representation of the data you need to unserialize from that object, which is still stored with some class information in the standard PHP serialization format.

The same data returned from your `serialize()` method (JSON string), will be passed to the `unserialize()` method, so there you have to pass it to `json_decode()` and set its properties yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't intend to implement `unserialize` because I just needed to pass the object data via AJAX without needing to reconstruct the state.

Comment: In that case you don't need serializable interface, `JsonSerializable` mentioned by @PunKeel seems to be better idea, or simply create your own interface with method like `getJSON()` and encode this object by calling it.